# Second await doesn't return proper value in method

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

I have an ansync method which gets called on an onClick-Event in Android.
In the method a few checks are made and then a search-method is called with await which sends a searchquery and gets a response.

Unfortunatley only the first time the search-method is called the program gets the proper return from the method. If I try using the search-method in the second if-block the search-method returns null.

I checked in the search-method whether it recieves the correct response or not and the problem seems to be in the return part because the correct respone is recieved in the search-method.

My code looks like this:

```
private async void CreateSearchQuery(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchQuery searchQuery = new SearchQuery();

        if (spinnerPosition == FIBU)
        {
            searchQuery.doctype = "Fibu Rechnungen";
            searchQuery.query   = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            searchQuery.query.Add("belegnr", belegnummer.Text);

            prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            var token = prefs.GetString("token", "");

            ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progress.Indeterminate  = true;
            progress.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
            progress.SetMessage("Suche nach Daten....");
            progress.SetCancelable(false);
            progress.Show();

            JArray searchresult = await SearchQuery.SendSearchQuery(searchQuery, token);
            progress.Cancel();

            FibuDocument[] documents    = searchresult.ToObject<FibuDocument[]>();
            var intent                  = new Intent(this, typeof(SearchFibuDetailsActivity));
            var json                    = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(documents);

            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
            editor.PutString("searchQuery", json);
            editor.Apply();       

            StartActivity(intent);                
        }

        if (spinnerPosition == AUFTRAGSBELEGE)
        {
            searchQuery.doctype = "Auftragsbelege";
            searchQuery.query = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            if(auftragsnummer.Text != "")
            {
                searchQuery.query.Add("auftragsnr", auftragsnummer.Text);
            }
            if(gstKode.Text != "")
            {
                searchQuery.query.Add("gst", gstKode.Text);
            }
            if(trackTrace.Text != "")
            {
                searchQuery.query.Add("sttnr", trackTrace.Text);
            }

            prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            var token = prefs.GetString("token", "");

            ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progress.Indeterminate = true;
            progress.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
            progress.SetMessage("Suche nach Daten....");
            progress.SetCancelable(false);
            progress.Show();

            JArray searchresult = await SearchQuery.SendSearchQuery(searchQuery, token);
            progress.Cancel();

            Document[] documents = searchresult.ToObject<Document[]>();

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(documents);
```

Comment: The code looks okay as far as I can tell. Did you check if the `token` is still valid? Are you sure that the `searchQuery` actually yields any results?

Comment: Yes I double checked that it yields any results and `token` is still valid. I can 100% confirm with debug mode that I get a result that is valid.

I think it has something to do with the two awaits I use because when I comment the content of the first `if` block I get the proper result.

Comment: Just a guess, but try using different instances of "searchQuery" rather than sharing one.

Comment: That worked! You can post it as a solution so I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different instances of "searchQuery" rather than sharing one.